# Explanation for the physics behind magnetic monopoles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-monopole

Ok so I am looking for a simple explanation of how the process is done from the information I could access and the knowledge I was allowed I have the idea that it is a matter of quantum physics and all i have understood is:

1. They freeze two magnets and split them not allowing the inner particle constellation to move freely and so it is stuck it its state as a monopole.
2. At room temperature it will go back to normal state (and doesn't this contradict with Curie I mean the Curie temperature isn't even close to room temperature and they say that magnetic materials maintain their magnetic properties before they reach that temperature).
3. When they touch they lose that state and they become regular magnets.

so how does this work being explained for a high school student in simplistic means i have seen some equations about it but they contain some theoretical physics equations and PDEs some even started explaining the theory of everything and so on,and though i love physics i plan not to self-learn PDEs and theoretical physics. I would really appreciate all the help I can get even if you give me a book that i can read to understand it.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95962/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95913/

Comment: Apparently this is a really new news? it looks like no one has answers yet..i did not know it was only yesterday that it was discovered/published! @KyleKanos TY this is actually enough ill research further into it later when it is less ambiguous...