# Quantum mechanical monopole

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-monopoles

Recently in physics news, scientists have experimentally discovered the so-called [quantum mechanical monopole](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/04/150430141602.htm#). It seems that a quantum mechanical monopole is different from a magnetic monopole. So my question is what exactly is a quantum mechanical monopole and what are the differences between the two if there are any.

Comment: There is a [more detailed description of the experiment on the nature web site](http://www.nature.com/news/quantum-cloud-simulates-magnetic-monopole-1.14612)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95913/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95962/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The thing is, they didn't observe a magnetic monopole (as in "a particle with magnetic charge"). Rather, they took a bunch of atoms, cooled them down to a temperature near the absolute zero (forming what is known as a _Bose-Einstein condensate_) and studied the behaviour of an electron in the vicinity of this condensate. The electron effectively "saw" a magnetic monopole. In the links provided by @Qmechanic you can find other examples of such "synthetic monopoles". For "real" monopoles, follow the MoEDAL experiment at CERN.